Conversion between euler and quaternion rotation produces incorrect results when using multiple angles
I'm trying to apply a previous answer to my code, I double-checked it on multiple sites where others came up with the same algorithm independently, but no matter which version I use I can't get the correct result. I need to convert an Euler rotation in degrees into a Quaternion rotation then back, one of the functions breaks and I get incorrect results when using multiple angles. Here are my functions adapted to my desired rotation order (X = roll, Y = yaw, Z = pitch) with a simple test that turns an angle to a quaternion then back to euler.
import math

def to_quaternion(x, y, z):
    rx = math.radians(x)
    ry = math.radians(y)
    rz = math.radians(z)

    sx = math.sin(rx / 2)
    cx = math.cos(rx / 2)
    sy = math.sin(ry / 2)
    cy = math.cos(ry / 2)
    sz = math.sin(rz / 2)
    cz = math.cos(rz / 2)

    x = sx * cz * cy - cx * sz * sy
    y = cx * sz * cy + sx * cz * sy
    z = cx * cz * sy - sx * sz * cy
    w = cx * cz * cy + sx * sz * sy

    return (x, y, z, w)

def to_euler(x, y, z, w):
    t0 = 2 * (w * x + y * z)
    t1 = 1 - 2 * (x * x + y * y)
    t2 = 2 * (w * y - z * x)
    t2 = +1 if t2 > +1 else t2
    t2 = -1 if t2 < -1 else t2
    t3 = 2 * (w * z + x * y)
    t4 = 1 - 2 * (y * y + z * z)

    dx = math.degrees(math.atan2(t0, t1))
    dy = math.degrees(math.atan2(t3, t4))
    dz = math.degrees(math.asin(t2))

    return (dx, dy, dz)

rot_1 = (0, 45, 90)
rot_2 = to_quaternion(rot_1[0], rot_1[1], rot_1[2])
rot_3 = to_euler(rot_2[0], rot_2[1], rot_2[2], rot_2[3])
print(rot_3)

When using a single angle of rotation it works fine, but when introducing more than one angle the result gets garbled. For example (0, 0, 90) behaves as expected, but in this test (0, 45, 90) will return (0, 26.56505117707799, 90) instead of itself. Which function is wrong and how do I address it?

First, don't compare Euler Angles. Multiple AE can describe same rotation. You can compare rotation matrices
